# Catching data on the php side from ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm confused. How do I catch the value on the php side after passing the data from ajax. Originally, I had data put into an object Array. When passing data through Ajax, do I pass it as a stringArray or as an ObjectArray? Does that mean I need to stringify() it?

**I'm doing this in MVC so that's why it's /test in the url**

```
<script>
    var objectArray = [{"name":"Robert", "type": "male"}, {"name":"Jane", "type": "female"}]
    var stringArray = JSON.stringify(objectArray);

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/test',
       data: stringArray,  //do I pass in objectArray or stringArray here?
       success: function(response)
       {
          alert(response);
       }   
    });
</script>   


test.php
<?php

public function test()
{
   $var = '';
   foreach($_POST['name'] as $value)
   {
       $var .= ' ' . $value;
   }
   return $var; // It says I'm getting unidentified index $_POST['name']
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP expects `key=value` pairs in GET/POST. You're passing in a monolithic string with no name, so PHP no key available to put that string into $_POST

Try

```
data: {foo: stringArray}
```

and

```
$_POST['foo']
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I got the response to return back the values now

Answer (score 0):

You should give a key for the value that you are trying to send to the backend and you don't really need to send it as a string. Like that:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/test',
   data: {users: objectArray },
   success: function(response)
   {
      alert(response);
   }   
});
```

Then, in your backend you should access the key you've sent. Like that:

```
public function test()
{
   $var = '';
   foreach($_POST['users'] as $value) // use the right key
   {
       $var .= ' ' . $value['name'];
   }
   return $var;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now I need to rethink this. Right now, I have 2 different data in the array, so I'll probably have to do a loop to get the key and value pairs